# How to write into Windows Registries in Guest account without asking Admin Privilege to Run my code

Tags: c#, windows, security, authentication, registry

Anyone knows if all my client computers are connected to my Server with a Specific Group Policy. I have restricted/guest privilege to all my client PC. I want to write a C# code which access/edit Windows Registry and I want to install into my client PC.

Since I know the Admin Password then is there any way to Save Admin password in some mainfest file and bypass the Admin Authentication window which ask for Admin privilege to run my code in guest PCs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use login scripts, or psexec, etc to run the app on every PC.
You can't run automatically as admin without installing a service or the task scheduler.